# SQL Server : continue inserting rows after exception

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that does an insert like this one:

```
    INSERT INTO [TargetTable] ([Hash], [Year], [Metadata])
        SELECT [Hash], [Year], [Metadata]
        FROM [SourceTable]
```

This query will fail because the `[TargetTable]` has data already and an unique index on the `[Hash]` column. It cannot insert duplicates.

How I can insert only the non-duplicates? I guess I could select first only the non-duplicates and then do the inserts. But the select would be more complex.

Another approach I tried is to ignore the duplicates. For instance:

```
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO [TargetTable] ([Hash], [Event], [Year], [Metadata])
        SELECT [Hash], [Event], [Year], [Metadata]
        FROM [SourceTable]
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```

I was expecting something like, try to insert this, if you cannot insert it, then ignore it, and then continue inserting the rest of rows.

Comment: You seem to be under the belief that SQl Server processes an `INSERT`, or at least within a `BEGIN TRY...CATCH` row by row. SQL Server works in datasets and will process the whole dataset in one go. If 1 row out of 1M has an error, then the entire statement errors and is rolled back. When working with a DBMS you need to not think in rows, and think in sets of data. This is why your second attempt didn't work. An `INSERT` doesn't work like a `FOR EACH` loop (nor does a `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, DELETE`, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no other inserts are happening at the same time, then this should work:

```
INSERT INTO [TargetTable] ([Hash], [Year], [Metadata])
   SELECT st.[Hash], st.[Year], st.[Metadata]
   FROM (SELECT st.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hash ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as seqnum
         FROM SourceTable st
        ) st
   WHERE seqnum = 1 AND -- ensure duplicates are not in source table
         NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TargetTable tt WHERE tt.hash = st.hash);
```